# Assigning color value to parameter's | dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

i have GridView where there is 40 buttons, that's one of them:

```
MyCalcButton(
       //clr: Colors.amber
         myNum: "2",
         funkcja: () {},
),
```

In my button class there are 2 required parameters, **`myNum`** and **`funkcja`** and one unrequired - > **`clr:`**. Now i want to change value (color) of this **`clr`** parameter some of those buttons, not every. Is there a way to assign this color to some of these and give rest of them one static color? Is it necessary to give one by one color for this **`clr`** ??

**There is class of this button**

```
String myNum = "";

class MyCalcButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCalcButton({Key? key, this.myNum, required this.funkcja, this.clr})
      : super(key: key);

  final Function funkcja;
  final myNum;
  final Color? clr;

  @override
  State<MyCalcButton> createState() => _MyCalcButtonState();
}

class _MyCalcButtonState extends State<MyCalcButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        widget.funkcja();
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
//maybe here i can change something to do this?? I dont know
        primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 204, 203),
      ),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        widget.myNum.toString(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide default value on parameter, in your case on `clr`

```dart
class MyCalcButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCalcButton({
    Key? key,
    this.myNum,
    required this.funkcja,
    this.clr =const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 204, 203),
  }) : super(key: key);
```

and use this like `primary: widget.clr,`.

---

Or just provide default value on null `clr` case like

```dart
primary: widget.clr ?? const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 204, 203),
```

---

If you like to update color within this state. you can create a local variable inside state class.

```dart
class _MyCalcButtonState extends State<MyCalcButton> {
  late Color? color = widget.clr;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        widget.funkcja();
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: color,
      ),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        widget.myNum.toString(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```